# Add missing month rows based on multiple columns with multiple variables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm very stuck and I was hoping you can help. So have the following dataset (*Table 1*) with **Month** (5 years worth), **Customer** (1000 customers), **Product** (100 products), **Units** and **Value** (value is just unit multiple a price). The data only shows rows with unit and value, so for customers when there is no sale in a month, there is no data.
[Click here for Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JppZg.png)

I want to create a table (*Table 2*) where every product for every customer is shown for all time periods, where actual units and values are included and those missing in Table 1 are now showing 0.
[Click here for Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnuQg.png)

I have read many posts here and elsewhere, which only handles 1 column (e.g. only **Customer** not both **Customer** AND **Product**, and only 1 measure not **Unit** and **Value**). I tried to adapt the code but failed miserably.

I also want to do this in *Power BI using **M** not DAX*, because I would like to further transform the data.

Thank you so much everyone!!!

Comment: Please do not post any pictures of the data. Insert your sample data into your question. And also show which dax formulas you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good afternoon.
You can use DAX to create a calendar for the required period of time.
Use the minimum and maximum values from Table 1 for the interval (Calendar function).

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(Date(2022,5,1), TODAY() -1)
```

Link the calendar to the necessary dates.

[calendar link example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruxvb.png)

In the settings of the table to which you will output data, select the "Show items without data" setting, and take the date from the calendar.

Comment: Thank you so much Ekaterina! Yes, I managed to get it to work. Just a few things I have learnt for others:

- When create the relationship with the time table use "Single direction"
- use calendar as primary key
- if you want to make calendar table only Months, it's a bit tricky and you can use this https://powerbi.tips/2017/12/start-of-month-dax-calendar/#:~:text=Open%20Power%20BI%20Desktop%2C%20on%20the%20Modeling%20ribbon,RETURN%20ROW%20%28%22day%22%2C%20day%2C%20%22month%22%2C%20month%2C%20%22year%22%2C%20year%29%29